# Multiple consumers trying to update same row of Mysql(5.7 version) table. How to fix concurrent update issue

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, isolation-level, pessimistic-locking

Multiple consumers are trying to update 'processedRecords' and 'erredRecords' fields of JobTracker. But I am facing issue where random values updated in these columns. Mysql is on default isolation level(MySQL version 5.7)

I thought of locking row by using PESSIMISTIC_WRITE. But following code doesn't give any exception and also row values are not updated. 
Someone please help me in resolving this.

Please note: 
 1. Any solution that changes isolation level for entire DB is not helpful as it would effect other flows in the application. 
 2. Both 'processedRecords' and 'erredRecords' are of type Long.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Boolean updateRecords(Long jobTrackerId, Long processedRecords, Long erredRecords) {
    try{
        JobTracker jobTracker = getEntityManager(true).find(JobTracker.class, jobTrackerId);
        getEntityManager(true).lock(jobTracker, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
        if(jobTracker == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(processedRecords!=null){
            jobTracker.setProcessedRecords(processedRecords);
        }
        if(erredRecords!=null){
            jobTracker.setErredRecords(erredRecords);
        }
        if(jobTracker.getErredRecords() != null && jobTracker.getProcessedRecords() != null && jobTracker.getTotalRecords() != null){
            if(jobTracker.getErredRecords() + jobTracker.getProcessedRecords() == jobTracker.getTotalRecords()){
                jobTracker.setStatus("Completed");
            }else if(jobTracker.getErredRecords() + jobTracker.getProcessedRecords() > jobTracker.getTotalRecords()){
                jobTracker.setStatus("Erred");
            }
        }
        getEntityManager(true).merge(jobTracker);
        return true;
    }catch(PersistenceException e){
        logger.error("For job id:" + jobTrackerId + " Exception while updating the jobTracker records data", e);
        return false;
    }catch (Exception e){
        logger.error("For job id:" + jobTrackerId + "Generic Exception while updating the jobTracker records data",e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When using `EntityManager` directly, I have always used `EntityManager.find(Class<T>, Object, LockModeType)`. Can you try that?

Comment: Yes, i tried with that. But faced same issue.
I could't find any exception in logs. But values were not updating. Basically logs after find was not logging.

Answer (score 0):

Using the @Transactional annotation we can set the isolation level of a Spring managed transactional method. This means that the transaction in this method is executed will have that isolation level. In your case, all you have to do is the following.

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
```

Now if you were to set the isolation level for your whole DB you would do the following.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
In my scenario i can't change isolation level for entire DB as it will effect other flows. 
I wanted to modify for this particular DB call.

Comment: Done, I just updated my answer. Now you should be able to set the isolation level for a specific transaction using Spring transactional manager. Please, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yes i tried with this annotation too. But the problem is, this annotation works for  4.2 + . Unfortunately our application uses 3.6. 

We get this exception if we use annotation in  3.6


    `HibernateJpaDialect does not support custom isolation levels since the \u0027prepareConnection\u0027 flag is off. This is the case on Hibernate 3.6 by default; either switch that flag at your own risk or upgrade to Hibernate 4.x, with 4.2+ recommended`.